Why can't I use a NpgsqlParameter for a channel or a payload in npgsql notify
I want to execute an NOTIFY in a Postgres RDBMS by c# library npgsql.
in SELECTS, INSERTS or UPDATES I used NpgsqlParameters to keep them flexible and save. So I thought, I could also use NpgsqlParameter für a channel name of the NOTIFY query. But I get a syntax error. When I use string concatenation insted, the syntax error is away.
private readonly string notifyChannel = "MYNOTIFY";
private readonly string notifyQuery = $"NOTIFY :notify_name;";
using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(notifyQuery, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("notify_name", DbType.String)).Value = notifyChannel;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

The Postgres version is 8.3, npgsql is 4.0.17.
(I know, that payload for notifies is not supported in Postgres 8.3.)

In all databases, parameters are used to pass values only, just like function parameters in C#. Those values never become part of the query itself. This isn't a string interpolation operation

I was afraid of that. The semantic of a NpgsqlParameter is different of my usage. So in newer version of postgres also notify payloads would not work a parameters?

You should be thankful for that - that's what prevents SQL injection, in all databases. This isn't about database versions. If you wanted to use the parameter for string interpolation anyway, why not use string interpolation? BTW $"NOTIFY :notify_name;" does nothing and there's probably a squiggle warning that since there's no interpolation parameter this is just a string. If you verify that the name is valid (eg matches a specific regex pattern like ^[A-Z]+$) the query will be safe in this particular case

The reference to the version was only, because payload for notify is not support in postgres 8.3. And a little hope was that maybe payload is, what we call a parameter in newer postgres versions.

That's not a payload, that's the object name. The question is sending a notification without a payload. Have you tried doing what you ask in pgAdmin or DBeaver first?

Yes, I did. In postgres 8.3 I can only do
NOTIFY channelname; since in Postgres 9 I can call NOTIFY channelname, payload;

You have bigger issues, Postgres 8.3 is ~11.5 years past EOL and version 9 is 9 years past EOL. Support for both has long since gone away.

These are old existing systems, no chance to upgrade. What a luck, that the npgsql-guys still are maintaining npgsql 4.0.x which is compatible. So I can develope a modern client.
